# FlashLight/Elastic Search Get the all fields of the resultant record

Tags: android, elasticsearch, firebase-authentication

I am using [flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) which provides a solution to make content search over firebase database and i am facing a problem that I have a database consists of posts where any post consists of:-

```
{
title : "",
Body :""
TimeStamp :""
Author :""
}
```

and in the `config.js`, I defined my paths as follow

```
exports.paths = [
{
path : "posts",
index: "firebase",
type : "thing",
fields: ['title']
}}
```

the result of the search contains:-

```
_source {
title : ""
}
```

How do i make the ES to return all the post document fields not only the "title" field?

Answer (score 0):

`fields:['title']` means that `title` is the only field indexed. The `fields:` parameter says "index these properties and these properties only" Basically, you are indexing *only* the `title` property, so there's nothing else to be returned when querying type `thing`.

To return your whole `post` object, simply remove the `fields:` property when defining your path. This will default to index everything in your `https://<instance>.firebaseio.com/posts` path.